# Text language based decision making

Tags: c, text, graphics, polymorphism, pic

I am currently developing with MPLAB X (IDE) on PIC32 platforms using C programming language.

I have a MAJOR project coming up which includes displaying graphics and text on a TFT screen.
We develop our systems for multiple languages ,including languages written "right to left" & "left to right".
So some symbols also change their position, and texts change their alignments on the screen.

So far Iv'e seen my former developer implement the code in a way that every screen displayed, or every object presented on the screen is tested for the language selected and then takes actions accordingly.

e.g:

```
/**Some actions shared by all the languages**/
.
.
/* language specific actions: */
if(language == lang1){
  .
  .
  /* Performs some actions */ 
  /* e.g: */ 
  displayText(txt, LEFT_ALIGNED);
  .
  .
} else if(language == lang2){
  .
  .
  /**SAME** actions with only minor changes depending on the language selected. */
  /* e.g: */ 
  displayText(txt, RIGHT_ALIGNED);
  .
  .
} else if.... (and so on)
```

As you can see, it seems quite an overhead, and the code this way has a lot of superfluous code duplication, especially when this structure is repeated inside almost every function/source file.

I am trying to think of an approach for developing more of a "polymorphic" structure that would not require so many "if else" statements.

I tried to search the internet for some examples implementing text based decision making, but was unable to find what I need, mostly due to the fact that I find it hard to describe my question.

I hope this is not somewhat a vague question,
but is there any structural consensus for implementing this kind of situations?

Many Thanks,
Tsoof A.

Comment: Text base decision making aside. Is the person a **former developer** because they never heard of functions?

Comment: Functions were in use, function pointers wasn't...

Comment: When I read `**SAME** actions with only minor changes depending on the language selected.` I see `Something that could have been extracted to another function with some control flags`.

Comment: I agree on that,
So if for the example that I gave (which I modified a little to provide more info)

A better implementation would be to use a flag, and that is how I've done that so far.

But that still seems a bit overhead.

As "DYZ" recommended maybe function pointers are the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for an array of language/action structures, then search the array for the language in question, and execute the associated action:

```
typedef struct {
  char *lang;
  void (*action)();
} action_t;

action_t actions[] = {{"en", func1}, {"de", func2}, ...};
...
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(actions)/sizeof(actions[0]); i++)
  if(!strcmp(actions[i].lang, language)) {
    actions[i].action();
    break;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be a good approach.
I will try to figure out how to implement it in my project.